# Google Cloud: open custom port in a network

Tags: cloud, google

I created one virtual machine on Google cloud and run a tcp listener on tcp port 3000.
That port is accessed on that virtual machine with internal IP address.
Site browse through the external IP address, but port can't open on external IP address.
Firewall rules also added in that instance.

Answer (score 0):

Using Cloud Shell, could you paste the output of:

gcloud compute firewall-rules describe [FIREWALL_RULE_NAME]

gcloud compute instances describe [INSTANCE_NAME] --zone=[ZONE]

There are several option on why the rule is not applying. With this information I will be able to help you.